# Predicate annotations

Tags: prolog

What's the Prolog way of adding "annotations" (meta information) to predicates?

A typical example from Java would be:

```java
@Transactional
public List<User> findAll() { ... }
```

What are the Prolog options for adding `Transactional` annotation to the predicate:

```
users(Users) :- ...
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no (de facto) standard solution. Some systems use predicate directives (e.g. Ciao Prolog, ECLiPSe, ... also Logtalk) that are in some cases user-extensible in the information they can represent. some system use structured comments (e.g. SWI-Prolog). But no matter the solution specifics, the best systems allow that information to be programmatically retrieved using the system reflection API so that we can base developer tools on it.

Comment: What do you think of a meta predicate `meta(my_predicate, transactional).` placed just above the actual definition of `my_predicate`?

Comment: Depends on the system that you're using. E.g. on Logtalk you would add that information as a user-defined key-value pair to the predicate `info/2` directive. That information would then be included in the generated API documentation and available from the reflection API. On a system providing term-expansion, you could defined e.g. a `transactional/1` directive and then expand it as needed. Is the purpose of such directive other than documenting?

Comment: I am trying to bridge the gap between Java/Spring and Prolog. Spring would use meta information to wrap the original method into a bigger method (with some boilerplate that nobody's interested in writing). So in Prolog, it probably corresponds to `meta/info` predicate guiding term expansion.